# old statement not working after delete trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I have tree tables `news`, `news_files` and `files`

```
news
    id  name
    1   valodik
    2   gugushik

news_files
        id  news_id  file_id
         1     1        5
         2     1        6
         3     2        9

files
        id  file_path
         5   /opt/storage/
         6   /opt/storage/        
         9   /opt/storage/
```

I am created `trigger` on `news_files`

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_delete_files AFTER DELETE ON news_files
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM files WHERE id=old.file_id;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

I want to delete data is table `news` it automatically delete rows in `files` tables, `news_files.news_id` is constraint cascade to `news.id`
example

```
delete from news where id = 1;
```

automatically delete two rows in table files.

Comment: I think you just want a foreign key constraint with `on cascade delete`.

Comment: What's the point of the `news_files` table if files cannot have an independent lifetime compared to `news`? Why doesn't files have a direct `news_id` column?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  but I have such a structure, one to many

Comment: You'd need something like `news_files` if you wanted *many to many*, and in fact that's what it supports. Nothing stops two `news` items referencing the same `file` and nothing stops one `news` item referencing multiple `file`s. You usually do one-to-many by having a direct foreign key in the many table.

Comment: @Shadow my question is not duplicate